# JScrollPane не прокручивает панель

Tags: eclipse, java, jscrollpane

У меня есть класс (Game), в котором в JScrollPane добавлена панель map, сама панель map заполняется панелями класса MapElement. При этом панель map больше размеров окна, но JScroll её не пролистывает. Как это исправить ? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Вот код
Код класса Map

```
public class Map extends JPanel {
Timer time = new Timer();
int size = 52;
//GameMenu gmen= new GameMenu();
int px, py;
int mx, my;// положение мышки
Dimension sSize;
int shig, swid;

boolean shouldmove;
MapElement mapelem[][] = new MapElement[60][40];

public Map() {
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this);
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 651, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 445, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    setLayout(groupLayout);

    addMouseListener(new Mouse());
    addMouseMotionListener(new Mouse1());
    sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    swid = sSize.width;
    shig = sSize.height;

    System.out.println(shig);
    loadmap();
    makemap();

    time.schedule(task, 1, 10);
}

public void savemap() {

}

public void loadmap() {

}

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        //movemap();
    }
};



public void makemap() {

    for(int x=0;x<60;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<40;y++){
            createObl(x,y,MapElement.Water,0);
        }
    }

    repaint();
    updateUI();




}
public void createObl(int x,int y,int category,int own){
    if(mapelem[x][y]!=null){
        remove(mapelem[x][y]);
    }
    mapelem[x][y]=new MapElement(y*100+x,category,own,size);
    mapelem[x][y].setBounds(x * size + px, y * size + py, size-2, size-2);
    add(mapelem[x][y]);

}


}
```

Код класса Game

```
public class Game extends JPanel {

Map map= new Map();
GameMenu gamemen= new GameMenu();
public Game() {
    Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int swid = sSize.width;
    int shig = sSize.height;
//System.out.println("high map ="+map.getSize().getHeight());
    setLayout(null);
    map.setSize(61*map.size, 41*map.size);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(0, 75, swid, shig);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(map);
    map.setLayout(null);
    add(scrollPane);
    gamemen.setBounds(0, 0, swid, 75);
    add(gamemen);
}

}
```

Вот класс MapElement

```
public class MapElement extends JPanel {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -373173344652368936L;
Color Countrycolor;
public final static int Ground = -8000054, Water = -777775445, Lake = -898455454, RUS = -222222298,
        USA = -987546548, UK = -95847245, China = -1216586558, Japan = -547862184, GER = -254789554,
        Country6 = -66556468, noOwn = -999999845;
int x, y, px, py;
int size, nomer, category;
int own;
double oil, gaz, ugol, wood, iron, metal, granit;

public MapElement(int nomer,int category,int own, int size) {

    this.size = size;


    this.nomer = nomer;


if (category == Water) {

        setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    }
    if (category == Lake) {
        setBackground(new Color(50,160,225));
    }
    if (category == Ground) {
        switch (own) {
        case RUS:
            Countrycolor = Color.RED;
            break;
        case USA:
            Countrycolor = Color.darkGray;
            break;
        case GER:
            Countrycolor = Color.YELLOW;
            break;
        case UK:
            Countrycolor = Color.GREEN;
            break;
        case China:
            Countrycolor = Color.ORANGE;
            break;
        case Japan:
            Countrycolor = Color.CYAN;
            break;
        case Country6:
            Countrycolor = Color.MAGENTA;
            break;
        case noOwn:
            Countrycolor = Color.lightGray;
            break;
        case 0:
            Countrycolor = Color.lightGray;
            break;
        }
        setBackground(Countrycolor);
    }
}

public void choseColor() {

}

}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Относительно `JScrollPane` проблема в следующем коде:

```
public Game() {
    Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int swid = sSize.width;
    int shig = sSize.height;
//System.out.println("high map ="+map.getSize().getHeight());
    setLayout(null);
    map.setSize(61*map.size, 41*map.size);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(0, 75, swid, shig);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(map);
    map.setLayout(null);
    add(scrollPane);
    gamemen.setBounds(0, 0, swid, 75);
    add(gamemen);
}
```

Во-первых, вы задаете вызовом `scrollPane.setBounds(0, 75, swid, shig);` размер `scrollPane` равный размеру экрана и со смещением в `75` по `y`, поэтому `scrollPane` просто не влезает во экран, и полоса прокрутки снизу не видна. Если нужно разместить панель инструментов и область прокрутки под ней, используйте `BorderLayout` примерно так:

```
setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
add( gamemen, BorderLayout.NORTH );
```

`BorderLayout` сам все растянет учитывая предпочитаемые размеры (preferred size).

После этого полоса прокрутки появится, но работать не будет. В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) сказано:

> By default `JScrollPane` uses `ScrollPaneLayout` to handle the layout of
>   its child Components. `ScrollPaneLayout` determines the size to make the
>   viewport view in one of two ways:
>
> 1. If the view implements `Scrollable` a combination of `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize`, `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth`
>      and `getScrollableTracksViewportHeightis` used, otherwise
> 2. `getPreferredSize` is used.

Т.е. в вашем случае, `JScrollPane` ориентируется на `getPreferredSize()`. Простейшим решением будет написать:

```
map.setSize(61*map.size, 41*map.size);
map.setPreferredSize( map.getSize() );
```

Но лучше переопределить `getPreferredSize` в вашем `Map`.